# Function not called after splitting code in multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried to structure my application with all my endpoints in one file and have those endpoints call or execute code in another file. When I reach my `/` route, the `getindexPage` function does not seem to get called at all. How do I make the program execute the code in the home.js file? Thank you.

routes.js

```
var home = require('../routes/home.js');
module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        //no functional code
        home.getIndexPage(); //Function call does not seem to work.

    });
};
```

home.js

```
var ejs = require('ejs');

function getIndexPage (req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs'); 
    res.console.log('got to function');
    //No console message, no error.
};

module.exports.getIndexPage = function getIndexPage() { };
```

Comment: There's absolutely no question in this post...

Comment: are you sure about res.console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. First you do not pass req and res to your function call. Second, you are exporting an empty function.

```
//routes.js
app.get('/', home.getIndexPage);

//home.js
module.exports.getIndexPage = getIndexPage;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! What if I wanted to run two or more functions off the home page.

Comment: Well, since you do not want any functional code in your route, call them inside the getIndexPage function...